# How? If $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n} = a$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+m} = a$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I was watching a lecture on Mathematical Analysis and the teacher gave the following example :

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n} = a$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+m} = a$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

I got totally confused by this example and totally lost my understanding of the limits.

I need an explanation of this example. Is it correct? if so, then how?

Comment: $(a_n)=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\ldots)$

$(a_{n+3})=(a_4,a_5,a_6,\ldots....)$

Ypu only "loose" the first 3 elements.

The same occurs for any $m\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Do you realize that this is just saying that of $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ converges to $a$, then $a_{m+1},a_{m+2},a_{m+3},\ldots$ *also* converges to $a$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  $$a=\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = \lim_{(n+m) \to +\infty} a_{n+m} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+m} = \lim_{m\to +\infty} a_{n+m} $$  I was just curious.  Doing this is probably invalid, right?  (I don't know these topics) Thanks...

Comment: Since $m$ is a fixed integer, the last expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks I missed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a_n)$ converges to $a$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. If this is the case then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists (you can take the same $N$, since $n+m > n \geq N$) $N \geq 1$ such that $|a_{n+m} - a| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$, as desired.